# How can I easily generate $\rm GaAs$ band structure?

Tags: electronic-band-theory, molecular-dynamics, non-linear-optics, density-functional-theory, tight-binding

Is there a program where I can easily generate $\rm GaAs$  band structure that shows lowest conduction band valleys?

Comment: Something like https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.82.205212 ? What do you consider 'simple' or 'easy'?

Comment: By easy/simple I meant there already code available so that I can regenerate the diagram and derive other properties like DOS and effective mass.

Comment: OK, https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.22.3886 is another place to start.

Comment: If you are looking for a plug and play fully set up code, you might have difficulties. On the other hand, implementing the Chen/Sher paper was a homework assignment 40 years ago...

Comment: You may get a detailed answer if you post the question in the new matter modelling SE: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com